# Primefaces DataGrid - CommandLink is not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i have an issue with nested UI components which is probably a known bug in PrimeFaces and Mojara. However I have no idea how can i solve it.

We have a image gallery with uploader and I want to be able to delete images from the datagrid, so

XHTML:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{pictureManagementBean.handleFileUpload}"  
                    mode="advanced"  
                    update="gallery messages"  
                    auto="true"                    
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                    />  

            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

            <p:dataGrid var="item" value="#{pictureManagementBean.pictures}" id="gallery">  
                <p:panel header="#{item.pictureName}" style="text-align:center">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">  

                        <p:graphicImage value="#{item.thumbnailDir}" />                             
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.createdate.toString()}" />                           
                        <p:commandLink value="Delete" 
                                       action="#{pictureManagementBean.removePicture(item.idpicture)}" ajax="false"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>  
                </p:panel>  
            </p:dataGrid>  

        </h:form>
```

Basically what is not working at the momment - at all - is the commandLink Delete in the DataGrid. The rest is fine.

Is there any walkaround to this? I've tried: columns, ajax, no ajax... nothing works. All i can do is get the button outside the DataGrid. But that's not really what I want.

Any help apprecieated.

**[small thing: surprisingly I have used commandLink in DataTable and Columns with no problem! ]**

Primefaces 3.4RC1 from maven. (didnt work on 3.3.1 either)

ok so I've found one thing:
**inside `<p:dataGrid>` if I use anything BUT p:columns its not working.
But then the view is terrible... should I just use CSS to fix it?**

Comment: `PictureManagementBean` is view scoped, right?

Comment: What exactly is not working with the commandLink? If simply nothing happens try to explicitely update the `dataGrid`.

Comment: A quick look into the doc reveals that the `p:panel` should be placed inside a `p:column`

Comment: Without a `<p:column>` tag or dynamically created columns in your managed bean, every element for every row of your datatable will have the same client id.  You need this if you want any functionality on the page to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Maple_shaft you are so right!

correct code:

```
<p:dataGrid var="item" value="#{pictureManagementBean.pictures}" id="gallery">  
                <p:column>
                    <p:panel header="#{item.pictureName}" style="text-align:center"> 
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%"> 

                        <p:graphicImage value="#{item.thumbnailDir}" />                             
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.createdate.toString()}" />                           
                        <p:commandLink value="Delete" 
                                       action="#{pictureManagementBean.removePicture(item.idpicture)}" ajax="false"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataGrid>
```

So just simple column element. I've just places it wrong before. Thanks so much.

Of course backing bean is @ViewScoped!