# PrimFacse Linkbutton doesn't work inside dataGrid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, java-ee-7

Good morning everybody,
I have a problem related to the primfaces controls.
I put a commandLink inside dataGrid, but the commandLink didn't get in the action method.
I don't why. So can you help me in this problem PLZ
Here is the code

```
<f:view>
<h:form>
    <p:tabView style="width: 420px;">

        <p:tab title="Events">

            <p:dataGrid value="#{EventDataTable.model}" var="event"
                        paginator="true" rows="3" columns="1"
                        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink}"  
                        paginatorPosition="bottom"
                        styleClass="ui-datagrid-no-border" 
                        >
                <p:fieldset style="width:285px;height:150px" legend="#{event.eventDto.title}">

                    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="5">
                                <p:graphicImage value="#{event.image}" />  
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                Title: <p:outputLabel id="title" value="#{event.eventDto.title}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>

                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                Date: <p:outputLabel id="date" value="#{event.eventDto.date}"/>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                Content: <p:outputLabel id="desc" value="#{event.eventDto.content}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <p:commandLink value="View More" actionListener="#{EventDataTable.doSomething()}" ajax="false"/>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                </p:fieldset>

            </p:dataGrid>
        </p:tab>
        </f:view>
</h:form>
```

This the bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="EventDataTable")
@RequestScoped
public class EventBean  implements Serializable{

 @PostConstruct
    public void initial() {
        try {
            System.out.println("test init");
            List<EventDto> eventDtos = event.findEventByUserId(2);
            List<EventWrapper> eventWrappers =  new EventConverter().convert(eventDtos);
            model = new ListDataModel<EventWrapper>(eventWrappers);
            System.out.println("the size=" + model.getRowCount());


        } catch (ApplicationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public EventBean() {
    }
 public void doSomething() {
        //Doing Redirection will be here
        System.out.println("The selected number is " + model.getRowIndex()+"*****************************");

    }
}
```

Comment: You should show some code of your bean, related with your `p:commandButton`... also are you really on JSF 1.2? What is the version of PrimeFaces ?

Comment: I dont see any p:commandLink in your form. Also does your datagrid fetch the values correctly? As I see your bean name is uppercase (EventDataTable). And finally have you tried debug it that method get executed and there is some weird try/catch mechanism doesnt show to stacktrace maybe?

Comment: I am sorry, now I put the code that has the problem.

Comment: I am using Primfaces 3.2 and JSF 2.1

Comment: @Yasmin you should include relevants parts of your bean ie: at least declaration (scope and name) and also the `doSomething()`.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie
I attached it to the question above.

Comment: @Yasmin You should try move your bean to `@ViewScoped`

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie
I tried it but still not working.

Comment: @Yasmin your tags are not properly closed at the end... is this a post mistake or your real code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces DataGrid - CommandLink is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985305/primefaces-datagrid-commandlink-is-not-working). It's also in the primefaces user manual

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Do you mean the commandLink shouldn't be self closed??

Comment: @Yasmin `p:tabView` is not closed and `h:form` and `f:view` are closed the invert they suppose to

Answer (score 0):

There is no form in your xhtml. Wrap the datatable in a form

Comment: No there is a form in the previous xhtml.