# p:commandButton inside p:dataList with paginator does not trigger the action after the paginator is used

Tags: primefaces, el, jsf-2.2

I have an xhtml like this:

```
<p:dataList id="accordion"
    value="#{myBackingBean.beans}" var="bean" 
    paginator="true" rows="3" effectSpeed="fast"
    paginatorTemplate=" {CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40" type="none"
    paginatorPosition="both">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                                <ui:include src="another_file.xhtml"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
</p:dataList>
```

Inside another_file.xhtml I have:

```
<ui:fragment xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

            <p:commandButton process="@this" value="text of t hebutton"         actionListener="#{myBackingBean.meEvent(bean)}" update="@this"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

When I load the page, the function `myBackingBean.meEvent(bean)` is correctly called.
When I switch to another page, using the PrimeFfaces paginator, the function is no more called.

Any idea on how I could solve it?

Comment: Your commandbutton should be enclosed in a `<p:column/>` to be able to execute in a datalist

Comment: @kolossus are you sure?? I do not have primefaces right now, but `<p:column>` is not used in the datalist: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml

Comment: [`dataGrid` has the same "feature"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985305/primefaces-datagrid-commandlink-is-not-working). I imagine the same might be true for a datalist